# Why std::ranges::view_interface using CRTP

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

According to cppreference, the helper class template for defining views [`view_interface`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface) using the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) techniques.

What is the design philosophy behind them? Is there a dramatic advantage versus overriding a virtual base class method in the derived class?

Comment: A view is non owning and light weight. Keep that in mind. Inheriting is not.

Comment: @doug: Inheriting from a type with virtual functions is not light-weight.

Comment: @doug `single_view<std::function<void()>>` is owning and not _quite_ light-weight.

Comment: @NicolBolas I should have been clearer and said neither instead of not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you give a base class virtual functions, then it has those functions. Always. It can never *not* have those functions, and every class derived from it will inherit those functions.

`view_interface` has an `empty` function if and only if the range category for the type is `forward_range`. That is, `empty` exists if `begin` returns a forward iterator, and `end` returns a sentinel for that iterator. But you can only test that if you can query properties of the derived class. And the base class can't do that... unless you allow it to by giving it the derived class type. Which means it has to be a template parameter, and the base class is a template.

And therefore, you're using CRTP.

Providing common functions or not based on the iterator categories of the derived range class is *the entire point* of the class. The only alternative is to have a bunch of base classes for each iterator type. So you'd have `forward_view_interface` for forward ranges, `contiguous_view_interface` for contiguous ranges, etc. And that'd be painful. But it would start to experience multiplicative explosion, because some properties provided by `view_interface` are orthogonal to the iterator category.

For example `size` is provided if the range is a sized range. But that may happen for *any* iterator category, even input iterators. So you now need `sized_forward_view_interface`, etc.

Or you can just use the CRTP.