# Why C++20 filter_view has a .size member function?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I found this on cppreference:

> Following types are derived from std::ranges::view_interface and do
> not declare their own size member function, but they cannot use the
> default implementation, because their iterator and sentinel types
> never satisfy sized_sentinel_for:
>
> ```
> std::ranges::basic_istream_view
> std::ranges::filter_view
> std::ranges::join_view
> std::ranges::split_view
> std::ranges::take_while_view
> ```

This makes sense since those views can not calculate size in O(1). But I do not understand why then not make more than one base class for views, for example something like [view_interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface) but without size member?

I presume that one possible reason is that ranges are already a insanely complicated library, but maybe I am missing something else.

If you wonder why this is a problem: maybe it is not, but I think/feel it is confusing to users since those views have member function that never works.

note: I know I can use distance, this is a question about design.

Comment: There is no `size()` in the base class of these range adaptors, I don’t understand what you want to ask

Comment: @康桓瑋    https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface/size

Comment: This is a constraint function, which constrains that `D` must satisfy `std::sized_sentinel_for<ranges::iterator_t<D>, ranges::sentinel_t<D>>`. In your example, the type of `D` is `filter_view`, which does not meet this requirement, so the `size()` function will not be instantiated.

Comment: @康桓瑋 yes, but the error message would be much easier to read if function did not exist in base class, compared to it being constrained with something >95% of C++ devs can not read.

Comment: If you specifically define an additional base class for `size()`, you probably need to declare an additional base class for `data()`, which is very redundant. This is also the reason why `view_interface` uses CRTP techniques, you can see more details about this design philosophy on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66094846/why-stdrangesview-interface-using-crtp).

Comment: @ NoSenseEtAl "*but the error message would be much easier to read if function did not exist in base class*", This is not enough and may be confusing when you want to know why it doesn’t have `size()`, but the error message of `constraint not satisfied` may help you find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class template is not a class. `std::ranges::view_interface` is not the base class of anything.

`std::ranges::view_interface<std::ranges::filter_view<V, Pred>>` *does not* have a `size` member. Other instantiations of `std::ranges::view_interface` do, but it's always been possible for one instantiation of a template to have members that another doesn't have.

The documentation for [`std::ranges::view_interface`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface) does mention that `size` is only present if (among other things) its sentinel and iterator type satisfy `std::sized_sentinel_for`.

I much prefer having *one* name that calculates appropriate capabilities, than a multitude of different names for subtly different capabilities. It is more extensible, if additional members are defined in later standards, everything automatically gains the members that it supports, without having to change e.g. `sized_forward_view_interface` to `foobar_sized_forward_view_interface`.